# How to get list of all Wi-Fi networks available in iPhone 5

Tags: wifi, iphone

My laptop is showing 4-5 wifi networks available in my area. But my iPhone is just showing 1-2 wifi networks. Even when I'm trying to add/search manually, then it is showing error **couldn't find network**. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Yet the question is quite imprecise. What is really asked? List of networks? Or why not all networks that laptop can see is seen on iPhone?

Answer (score 5):

Download the [Airport Utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airport-utility/id427276530) app from the app store and then in the settings app enable Wi-Fi Scanner.

[image]

You get a searchable list and export capabilities of the results. Once you have a scan, you can post those results in a new thread to ask what to do in your situation once you have concrete data.

Answer (score 4):

Your iPhone has a lower-power Wifi adaptor with a smaller antenna than your laptop. The networks it sees are probably the only ones it can connect to.

Comment: Correct.. But my friend's mobile (Nokia) can see all available network.

Comment: It only means that your friend's Nokia has stronger WiFi antenna or software allowing networks with less signal to show up. Or both.

Answer (score -1):

If it doesn't show up, you might be able to connect to it as a hidden network. It could be that your iPhone is too far away, and discards the network. Whereas, it may be wrong and it does have the network. This way, it connects.

Answer (score -5):

The thing about the iphones is that it can only get wifi a very short radius from the location(about 10 feet). So try moving your phone to a stonger location of your wifi so that you can access it.

Comment: Definitely a lot more than 10 feet.  Also, I'm not sure that this is really answering the OP's question.